Snowflake: GetInsertCommand Exception: Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any base table information
I am using the .net Snowflake.Data library V4.2 in a .Net 8.0 Web API application.
When I make a GetInsertCommand call I get the following error:
Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any base table information
My C# code has the following:
SnowflakeDbConnection snowConnection = (SnowflakeDbConnection)databaseConnection);
SnowflakeDbDataAdapter snowAdapter = new SnowflakeDbDataAdapter(request.TableSql, snowConnection);
SnowflakeDbCommandBuilder builder = new SnowflakeDbCommandBuilder(snowAdapter);
snowAdapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();

The exception is
PrivacyEtl.Components.Server.Adapters.PEtlAdapter+<PutData>d__25:MoveNext
Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any base table information.
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommandBuilder.BuildInformation(DataTable schemaTable)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommandBuilder.BuildCache(Boolean closeConnection, Boolean useColumnsForParameterNames)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand(DataRow dataRow, Boolean useColumnsForParameterNames)
   at PrivacyEtl.Components.Server.Adapters.PEtlAdapter.PutData(InsertDataRequestModel request, Object databaseConnection) in

I saw some posts where some problems were caused because the table did not have a primary key defined. The DDL for the table is:
create or replace TABLE SALES.BASE.CU_CREDIT_CARD_BALANCE_DEIDENTIFIED (
    ROW_ID NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL autoincrement start 1 increment 1 order,
    CITY VARCHAR(100),
    STATE_CODE VARCHAR(10),
    ZIP VARCHAR(10),
    CC_NUMBER VARCHAR(100),
    CC_BALANCE NUMBER(10,2),
    CC_TYPE VARCHAR(20),
    MIN_PAYMENT NUMBER(10,2),
    POLYID VARCHAR(50),
    constraint pk_cc_balance_deidentified primary key (row_id) 
);

I have tried defining the PK using the Primary Key clause by itself and not on the PK column but that does not make a difference.
Any ideas?
Thank you.
This application is designed to handle any table in any customer database so there is no way for me to know what the table looks like in development. I can catch this error and let the user know the table needs a PK, but I cannot really set the PK myself.
I use similar code for several different database providers (SQL Server, Teradata, etc.) without issue.

What's the actual query? As the error says, if the query doesn't produce any schema information, eg a SELECT 1;, there's no way to use that schema to create an INSERT query. The Snowflake provider unit tests show that DbDataReader.GetSchemaTable should work with eg SELECT * FROM SomeTable'.

Sorry, I should have included that. The query at this time is SELECT * from  and I agree, it should work.

Post the actual full query, not something like it. This error is generated because the actual query didn't return schema information. You need to verify that the query does return schema info. Use a SnowflakeCommand  with that query and call ExecuteDataReader. Then call GetSchemaTable. Do you get a schema table back? Does it look the way it should?

BTW almost nobody uses DbDataAdapter and DbCommandBuilder these days. Those classes made sense in Windows Forms, to allow loading a DataTable and binding it to UI elements or grids. In data loading scenarios it's better to use the provider's bulk loading features. SQL Server has SqlBulkCopy for example. It's far faster to upload data into whatever blob storage you use and then use COPY INTO to import it, or PUT to load it as a stage files

Regarding your question about GetSchemaTable, I am using FillSchema and it does give me the DataTable. I tried GetSchemaTable all the columns are there but the key column (see SQL above) row_id is not marked as unique or as a key column although that column is added as the primary key constraint. So, this process showed me what I thought was happening. I declared a table with a PK but when the Snowflake adapter reads the table structure, it is not pulling that key definition in.  Any ideas as to why not?

Also, I did post the full query. The query is 'SELECT * from '. The tablename value is dynamic. I do not know the table as it could be any table. Also, because the type of database (Sql Server, Snowflake, Teradata, Oracle, etc.) is dynamic. This is why I am trying to keep the flow and the types of classes used as consistent as possible.

The point isn't how to get the schema for any table, it's finding out why this particular query, against this particular database server fails*. You need to specify CommandBehavior.KeyInfo in ExecuteReader to get the key info but the Snowflake client implementation ignores the behavior parameter completely

Also, the data reader doesn't add key information to the schema at all, which is understandable, because it's never retrieved. The code you're trying to use won't work.

Your answer is unfortunate, but it is very helpful. Looks like I need to find a different way to write data to Snowflake.  Thank you.
